# Changing MaxClockSkew is not helping in decreasing server-client time difference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, time

I am developing an application that will be used world-wide. This application uses a centrally hosted WCF web service. Since the application can be accessed in different time-zones, I changed the maxClockSkew to 00:30:00 but still `The security timestamp is stale` exception is coming. I want to know what maxClockSkew must be set for such an application that can be used world-wide?

My full server config can be found here: [How to make WCF service server-client time difference independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400608/how-to-make-wcf-service-server-client-time-difference-independent)

Comment: maxClockSkew is related to differences in absolute time (UTC), which is the same everywhere. The fact that the clients are in different timezones shouldn't matter, as long as they have the correct time.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Add it as your answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maxClockSkew is related to differences in absolute time (UTC), which is the same everywhere. The fact that the clients are in different timezones shouldn't matter, as long as they have the correct time.