# Why client config shows wsHttpBinding when I have customBinding on server?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I am using `customBinding` on my WCF web-service. But when I add service reference from Visual-Studio 2012, the configuration of the client shows `wsHttpBinding` as shown below:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IService1" />
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

What is the reason behind this?

My full server config can be found here:[How to make WCF service server-client time difference independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400608/how-to-make-wcf-service-server-client-time-difference-independent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your custom binding is configured in a way that macthed the WSHttpBinding capabilities. According [WCF Binding converte](http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/)r, this is the custom binding that matches ws http default settings:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <transactionFlow />
    <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
      <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
    </security>
    <textMessageEncoding />
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

(your custom binding may be shorter since some of the above values are defaults so you may omit them)

Now - and this may be related to your other question - the time skew settings do not propogate with the WSDL from the server to the client. You need to manually configure them on both server and client.