# An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

When I try to execute a CRM CRUD operation using a Console App, I'm getting the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
>     HResult=0x80131501
>     Message=An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
>     Source=mscorlib

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         IOrganizationService _serviceProxy = crmConnection();

         Entity con = new Entity("contact");
         con["lastname"] = "test"; 
         _serviceProxy.Create(con);
    }
    private static IOrganizationService crmConnection()
    {
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    Uri oUri = new Uri("https://XXXXXXXX.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");          
    ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";  
    OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(oUri, null,clientCredentials,null);
    _serviceProxy.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    return _serviceProxy;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlgOh.png)

Comment: This may already be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484601/wcf-gives-an-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fault-error. If not, please provide more detail including the code you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your responce.Added code

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Connection String with XrmTooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect) this way you can avoid call directly to the Organization.svc and handle the redirection to the SDK

```
var conn = new CrmServiceClient("AuthType=Office365;Username=xxx@xxx.com; Password=yyyyyy;Url=https://xxxx.crm.dynamics.com;RequireNewInstance=True");
IOrganizationService _orgService = conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
return _orgService;
```

If the error continues could be related to differences between your PC time and the Dynamics Server ajusted +-4 minutes and try again.

Hope it helps